# .checked isn't working in my if statements

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm writing up a method for when a checkbox is ticked it increases a value, but for some reason .checked isn't working and giving me the error "The event 'ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=", here's the code:

```
private decimal calcOptionalExtras()
        {
            decimal optionalExtras = 0;

            if (tintingCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                optionalExtras = optionalExtras + 150;
            }
            return optionalExtras;
        }
```

If someone could offer some advice or a workaround I'd really appreciate that, thank you.

Comment: `optionalExtras` is scoped to the method. Every time the method is called, `optionalExtras` starts at 0. Did you look at the documentation for the type `ToggleButton` to see if, perhaps, there's a property like `IsChecked`? `Checked` is an event, not a property.

Comment: If this is WPF or UWP (impossible to tell since you only tagged xaml) then the property you need is called `IsChecked` since `Checked` is an event.

Answer (score 0):

I see directly your mistake, that what you wrote would be **correct in Forms** but **in WPF (that you use) you have to put an "Is" in front of it** so "IsChecked".

For this you have to **use "== true"**, **because you get a "bool?" from "IsChecked"**, so your can get a "true", "false" and "NULL".

See here:

```
private decimal calcOptionalExtras()
{
    decimal optionalExtras = 0;

    if (tintingCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        optionalExtras += 50;
    }

    return optionalExtras;
}
```

Just as information, you can also write this code like this:

```
private decimal calcOptionalExtras()
{
    decimal optionalExtras = 0;

    return tintingCheckBox.IsChecked == true ? optionalExtras += 50 : optionalExtras;
}
```

This is basically your If code, just prettier and more compact. But of course you can also use your way.